Powering an Outdoor Security Camera via USB - Need a Waterproof Solution
I'm setting up a Wi-Fi security camera that will be installed outdoors and powered via a USB-type A pigtail.
I'm looking for advice or solutions that address these specific requirements and challenges would be greatly appreciated!
My Situation and Specific Problem:

Power Requirement: The camera requires 5V DC at 2A (or more) via a USB type A port.

Power Source: I have two practical sources:
My preferred option is from my circuit box, run a 12 or 16 AWG SJTW cable. There is also a standard outdoor plug about 10 meters (32 feet) away. Weather

Protection: The USB power adapter/charger needs to be weatherproof due to the outdoor environment. If a waterproof adapter is not available, I can house it in a weatherproof junction box.


Challenges I've Encountered:

Finding a USB adapter/charger that can take 120V AC input via an SJTW cable without using an electrical outlet.
Finding an outdoor receptacle with "while-in-use covers" that can accommodate a standard USB adapter to replace the existing outdoor plug cover. However, I prefer not to use this option as I do not have a neat way of wiring the USB cable.

Current Solution Considerations:
Running an SJTW cable from my circuit breaker to a receptacle and connecting a standard USB adapter inside a waterproof junction box.

Product recommendations are off topic here. Please see the [help].

You know the answer. It doesn't exist.  Put a USB block behind a waterproof cover.

Look for outlet/receptacles with USB, if 120v to the block/box.

We do this in the Christmas Lights community all the time. The cool addressable Christmas lights take 5-24VDC with 30+ amps so power adapters like this Meanwell are common (I am not affiliated with Meanwell but I am a huge fan of their products).

We pack these inside weatherproof boxes large enough for these and all the controller electronics and use weatherproof glands for cables passing through to outside.
Your use case is even simpler; if you only need 5VDC @ 2A you could use a much smaller supply which means a much smaller weatherproof project box.
One other big difference in your use case is that you likely need permanent wiring for this camera and much of the Christmas lights gear is seasonal/temporary. If your camera space gets much sun, you might consider a solar charger; you can probably find one with USB output which simplifies things by putting all the electronics inside the panel's waterproof enclosure. My security camera's manufacturer makes their own solar chargers so I know they're compatible with my devices.

Thank you for your answer, so what I basically need is an AC to DC Power Supply Single Output, such as the MEAN WELL RS-15-5, and if needed, add to it a USB type A pigtail

Plug in the regular USB charger inside the house/building, as close to the camera as possible. You may be able to use an outlet in the nearest room, or wire up a code-compliant outlet up in the attic or basement corner/side nearest the camera.
Then run the 5VDC wire from the supply through a window frame (under the trim) or a roof soffit, or drill a hole through the wall like the cable TV installers do and use the weatherproof grommet they use, up to the camera.
The high voltage is inside where it belongs, and the low voltage can snake it's way outside much more easily and safely.
